# Injecting EJB in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ejb, java-ee-6

I am working on migration of JAVA EE project to spring boot project. So far I have no problem with the migration of this project. The problem is that my application uses a common-project which is developed in JAVA EE so it contains EJB.

I am looking for a solution haw can i inject these EJBs in my application.

I tried to create spring beans in my configuration class like this:

```
    @Bean
    public MyEJBService myEJBService(){
        return new MyEJBServiceImpl();
    }
```

and than I autowire my new bean if needed. It seems working but when my EJB contains other injected EJB I have to create it as bean like above.
In this way I have to create spring beans for all my EJBs. And the common-project contains a lot of EJBs.

Is there a way to inject my EJBs in a simpler way ?